# Monodroid will not deploy when using an ImageView

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have this in my `Main.axml`;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >

    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="200dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/Hello"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:src="@drawable/samplebackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MyButton"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It builds fine and sampleBackground is a jpg that has been included in my project.

However when I try to deploy I get an error;

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

And there are a bunch of lines stating `<filename unknown>`

If I remove the ImageView from the markup the application deploys fine.

Any thoughts?

**full stack**

------ Build started: Project: MonoAndroidApplication1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  MonoAndroidApplication1 -> C:\Development\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\bin\Debug\MonoAndroidApplication1.dll
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.225]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 8/06/2011 8:37:40 AM.
Project "C:\Development\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1.csproj" on node 1 (SignAndroidPackage target(s)).
_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir:
Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir" because it has no outputs.
_ResolveMonoAndroidSdks:
  Looking for Android SDK..
    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.
    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path found:
      Path contains adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk).
  Looking for Java SDK..
    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\CurrentVersion found: 1.6.
    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6\JavaHome found:
      Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25).
  MonoAndroid Tools: C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Novell\
  MonoAndroid Framework: C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.2\;C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\
  Android SDK: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\
  Java SDK: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\
_ValidateAndroidPackageProperties:
  GetAndroidPackageName Task
    ManifestFile: 
    AssemblyName: MonoAndroidApplication1
    PackageName: MonoAndroidApplication1.MonoAndroidApplication1
_UpdateAndroidResgen:
Skipping target "_UpdateAndroidResgen" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectoryAlways:
  Copying file from "C:\Development\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\Resources\Drawable-land\Icon.png" to "bin\Debug\Resources\Drawable-land\Icon.png".
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  MonoAndroidApplication1 -> C:\Development\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\bin\Debug\MonoAndroidApplication1.dll
ContractDeclarativeAssemblyCS:
Skipping target "ContractDeclarativeAssemblyCS" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_ConvertDebuggingFiles:
Skipping target "_ConvertDebuggingFiles" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_CompileAndroidPackage:
  Mandroid Task
    Assemblies: C:\Development\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\bin\Debug\MonoAndroidApplication1.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.2\Mono.Android.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll
    I18nAssemblies: 
    BuildDirectory: C:\Development\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\obj\Debug\
    ReferenceAssembliesDirectory: C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.2\;C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\;;
    AndroidSdkDirectory: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\
    JavaSdkDirectory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\
    AssetDirectory: C:\Development\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\obj\Debug\assets\
    AndroidSdkPlatform: 8
    MonoAndroidToolsDirectory: C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Novell\
    ResourceDirectory: C:\Development\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\obj\Debug\res\
    ManifestTemplate: 
    Package: MonoAndroidApplication1.MonoAndroidApplication1
    NativeLibrary: 
    JavaSource: 
    Debug: True
    UseSharedRuntime: True
    SupportedAbis: armeabi
    LinkMode: None
    ExtraArgs:
  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Novell\mandroid.exe -v --nosign --sdk-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk" --builddir="C:\Development\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\obj\Debug\android" --framework-dir="C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.2" --framework-dir="C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0" -S="C:\Development\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\obj\Debug\res" --package="MonoAndroidApplication1.MonoAndroidApplication1"   --nolink --abi="armeabi" --java-sdk-dir="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25" --debug --sdk-platform="8" -A="C:\Development\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\obj\Debug\assets" "C:\Development\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\bin\Debug\MonoAndroidApplication1.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.2\Mono.Android.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll" 
monodroid : error 1: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object [C:\Development\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1.csproj]
    at MonoDroid.Utils.ProcessRocks+c__Iterator5.MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0 
    at Monodroid.Toolbox.InvokeCommand (IEnumerable`1 commandLine) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Monodroid.Toolbox.InvokeAapt (System.String packageName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Monodroid.Droidinator.CreatePackagedResources (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 javaTypes) [0x00000] in :0 
    at Monodroid.Droidinator.CreateApk () [0x00000] in :0 
    at Monodroid.MainClass.Main (System.String[] argv) [0x00000] in :0 
Done Building Project "C:\Development\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Development\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target) (1) ->
(_CompileAndroidPackage target) -> 
  monodroid : error 1: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object [C:\Development\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1.csproj]

Comment: Can you post the full log from the logcat

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
I found the solution; **just make sure the image filename is in lowercase.**
My image was named Image.png by renaming it to image.png it worked.

---

It's easy enough to reproduce - just create a new solution with a layout with a ImageView. Set the `android:src="@drawable/Image"`. 
If I type the Image with lowercase, image, it gives a compiler error, but when i correct it to Image no compile time errors, but the packaging fails...
The Image is in the correct folder and set to AnddroidResource.

So I would indeed like some help on this one too.

Thanks, Nicklas

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Build Action for that image file is set to AndroidResource. You can set the Build Action by right clicking on the file in Visual Studio and selecting Properties.

Comment: Can you provide a sample project with the error? It's tough to say what's going on without seeing it, but judging from that output it looks like the image isn't being included in the build. I assume it's located in the proper Drawable folder(s)?

Comment: it's not possible to include the project but your'e right,  the image is in the drawable-land folder and it's the only drawable folder.  i also have a corresponding layout-land folder.